# How to position element in center vertically and

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have a view with a form (login, password, button) which should be vertically in centre when keyboard is not visible. When the keyboard is visible, it should take as much space from under the form and then move the form upward, only as much as necessary.

So on a small phone like iPhone SE the form might be moved up a lot, and on a big one, like XS Max the space under the form would be enough to fit the keyboard, so the form should not move.

I am trying to crack how to achieve it with flex and KeyboardAvoidingView.

My code looks like this:

```
 <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }} behavior={'padding'}>
     <View style={{ flex: 1 } />
     <View style={{ flex: 0 }}>
         <Form />
     </View>
     <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
 </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Unfortunately, it shrinks both Views with `flex: 1` equally and because of that - moves the form up, even when it's not needed.

I tried to fix it also with Keyboard events and Animated, but the experience seemed pretty poor - the form was being moved up only after the keyboard was already opened (I was using `KeyboardWillShow` event, not the Did one).

Comment: Please fix your title. Thank you.

Comment: try to use `justify-content: center`